# Increase the amount of brace expansions given a number

Tags: bash, brace-expansion

I have a program that uses a brace expansion:

```
for X in {a..z}
    do echo $X;
done
```

I want to increase the amount of letters used in the brace expansion with a provided number. For example if the number 3 is provided:

```
for X in {a..z}{a..z}{a..z}
    do echo $X;
done
```

If the number 5 is provided:

```
for X in {a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}
    do echo $X;
done
```

How can I do this in bash?

Comment: You can't, and you almost certainly would not want to. The expression is expanded immediately, *then* the iteration starts. `{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}` expands to nearly 12 million strings in memory first; it's not a lazy generator.

Comment: Alternative: Use a nested for loop. Nest the for loop you currently have under another loop or two.

Comment: Do you just want to generate all the possible combinations of n letters, or are you actually trying to do something else with this?

Comment: @AlexM I'm making a little bruteforcer for fun, and this will allow me to get all permutations of a certain set of letters

Comment: This would probably be easier in Python, using `itertools.permutations` and `string.ascii_lowercase`.

Comment: @saladCracker, ...but for the reason chepner suggested, you really **don't** want to implement it this way. Shell brace expansion is the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way. With `a..z`:

```
$ a2z() { 
  k=""
  n=$1
  while [ $n -gt 0 ]
  do
    k="{a..z}$k"
    let n="$n-1"
  done
  echo $(eval "echo $k")
}
$ for X in $(a2z 3)
do echo $X;
done
aaa
aab
aac
...
```

Kinda useful, or at least interesting, using `0..1` as it shows each permutation for N bits.

```
$ bitperms() {
  k=""
  n=$1
  while [ $n -gt 0 ] 
  do
    k="{0..1}$k"
    let n="$n-1"
  done
  echo $(eval "echo $k")
}
$ bitperms 4
0000 0001 0010 0011 0100 0101 0110 0111 1000 1001 1010 1011 1100 1101 1110 1111
$ for X in $(bitperms 2);do echo "$X";done
00
01
10
11
```

Comment: And, as @chepner mentioned - this will kill your system pretty quickly.

Comment: Yeah I know it'll kill the system, just making it for fun is all

Comment: BTW, I'd suggest `eval "echo $k"`, just to be a little more explicit about what's going on under the hood (and making it clear that `eval` actually operates on a single string). Doesn't matter for this use case, but there are plenty of other scenarios where letting `eval` string-split and glob-expand its individual arguments before concatenating them together to generate that string (which it then parses) lead to bugs.

Comment: Done - the quotes on that line had me confused. I didn't think `echo "$(eval "echo $k")"` would work correctly (it does) so I ended up leaving all the quotes out.